# R: check value of compile and load flags

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

R uses compile and load flags to compile C and C++ code, and I know that I can alter these flags using Makevars files in my ~/.R directory or inside a package. 
How can I query the value of one of these variables? From inside R, or also from the command line? For instance, I would like to know what the variable `LDFLAGS` evaluates to when I use the R function `install.packages` (ignoring the possible package-level Makevars). How do I do that?

I figured out that certain variables that can be used in a Makevars, such as `R_HOME`, can be queried by doing:

```
Sys.getenv("R_HOME")
```

So why is this method not working (returning an empty string) for flags such as `LDFLAGS` and `CXX_STD` ? Are they a different kind of variables than `R_HOME` ? Is there another method for these variables?

Thanks a lot,
Alessandro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I mostly need this while writing code rather than during run-time so I just grep the file.

But in general you can query this at the command-line via `R CMD CONFIG`:

```
$ R CMD config LDFLAGS
-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro
$
```